# Any way to connect to my PPTPD (VPN) while port 1723 is blocked?

Tags: networking, server, vpn

I've set up a VPN/PPTPD Network on my VPS with the intention to bypass the blocked ports at my work and in the train so I can watch youtube and stuff.
Now the problem is that when I try to connect to my VPN it throws me error 800.
So this basically means that port 1723 is blocked, which is pretty ironic.

(The remote connection was not made because the attempted VPN tunnels failed)

Is there any way to achieve my intensions?
Maybe another VPN server?